# Calling a Procedure in Select Statement

Tags: oracle

I have a package consists of function and procedures

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY schema.pkg_product as     
function xxxxx()
procedure  product_get(p_product_id    IN  Number,    
P_direct_balance Out Number,    
P_indirect_balance Out Number) IS    
v_request CLOB :=<soapenv:Envelope xmnlns:----->    
v request_end varchar(100) := <can:----->    
BEGIN    
   Selct statement     
END
```

My question is can we can Call the procedure in the select statement and how can I get the `P_direct_balance` , `P_indirect_balance`.  if so in the select query coz I want to retrieve that data from the procedure.

Comment: You can't call a procedure directly in SQL, but you can easily make a  wrapper function and call it instead.

Comment: If you need to be able to call your code in SQL, then write a function, not a procedure.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. You could write a function but you cannot use functions with out parameters in SQL. So you'll have to rewrite your code. For instance create two functions that return p_direct_balance and p_indirect_balance.

Answer (score 0):

If rewriting the procedure to be a function with an out parameter is not possible, I would suggest altering the procedure to write the relevant values to a temporary table and commit. Then use your select statement to retrieve the values from the temp table.